# Carrierwave - Delete file from Amazon S3 but keep the record on db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

I see we can use `object.file.remove!` or `object.remove_file!` to remove files from S3, but `object` still holds the `.file`.

I want to set `object.file` to nil or empty, because I want to remove the file from S3 but still want to keep the record on my database (for statistics purposes).

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: No... and I've stopped maintaining the project that uses carrierwave

Comment: Ha i see, does that mean you don't use it anymore? Is carrierwave not reliable?

Comment: No, it is still reliable, we just shutdown the project.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another field in your File table called *expired*. In the method that deletes the file from S3, use the update_attribute to change the expired field. If *expired* equals true then do not allow the "file" to be downloaded.

```
Document.update_attribute(:expired, true)
```

Comment: I'm currently with this solution but this isn't the answer to the question. =]